# Twig default filter or Null coalescing operator?

Tags: conditional, variable

When testing for a variable in a template these two appear to do the same thing. I've read CruftlessCraft's article on [How to check for undefined variables](https://cruftlesscraft.com/how-to-check-for-undefined-variables) but can't see an explanation of why I should use one over the other. In his examples (below) I note that only the default filter includes "" in the list of results, is that correct or significant?
Is one faster or more efficient?

```
{% if twigVariable|default %}
    Value is set and not empty
{% else %}
    Value is either undefined, false, 0, null, "", [] or {}
{% endif %}
```

or

```
{% if twigVariable ?? false %}
    The value is set and not empty
{% else %}
    Value is either undefined, false, 0, null, [] or {}
{% endif %}
```

Does it make any difference if I don't need a fallback or the else and am just wrapping it around a div that shouldn't be shown if the variable doesn't have any usable content?

Answer (score 3):

So things like the null coalescing operator make it easier to chain things, so if you have a number things to fall back on, it's much neater to write:

```
{% set woof = bark ?? howl ?? growl ?? null %}
```

...then it is to try to chain that all together with `| default` filters.

Something that may also make your life easier is the [Empty Coalesce plugin](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-emptycoalesce), so you can write:

```
{% set woof = bark ??? howl ??? growl ??? null %}
```

What's the difference? The null coalescing operator only checks for `null`, so if `bark = ""` then it'll choose that, which often isn't what you want for strings.

There's a writeup of all of this in [Handling Errors Gracefully in Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/handling-errors-gracefully-in-craft-cms#coalescing-the-night-away) article.

Now, what is going to be more performant? Unless you're in a massive inner loop (which we should avoid in a templating language anyway), I doubt it'll matter. PHP code is transpiled to a bytecode that often gets cached, it should be fine.

But in theory, `??` and `???` are probably marginally faster.

Comment: So am I right in thinking that if I don't want any fallback options the default filter is the best choice to test for existence of anything usable? I'd rather not be reliant on a third party plugin if I didn't need to, but if I did need to I'd be happy if it was one of yours. I had read your excellent Handling Errors article but wasn't 100% sure it was all valid for Craft 3, as there are so many small subtle changes that are easy to miss when moving from Craft 2.

Comment: Use whatever is the most readable to you, imo. That "Handling Errors" article was written for Craft 3, but it applies for Craft 2 as well. I think it's totally fine and understandable to just use the `default` filter if your case is simple.